# Datagridview doesn't show records from database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm just want to code a button that displaya the today incoming.

[image]

```
con.Open();
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Sales Where SaleTime Like '"+ dateTimePicker1.Value +"'",con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
SalesGridView.DataSource = ds;
con.Close();`
```

Comment: Is SaleTime a DateTime column in your db? In this context you are converting a datetime (the picker value) to a string and then you ask your db engine to convert it back to a datetime. A lot of things could go wrong here. Use parameter to query a database

Comment: what **EXACTLY** is your problem?

Comment: yes saletime is in db and it is datetime, sorry , so my problem is i create a button with the upper code and its return with an empty datagridview

Comment: Then you cannot search a datetime column passing a string with the LIKE operator. You should learn how to build a parameterized query. Add a parameter of type DateTime using the DatePicker.Value without converting it to a string. Probably your current query is unable to find any record because the database engine is not able to convert correctly your string back to a datetime